# Limiting behavior of sde

Tags: stochastic-calculus

What can we say about the limiting behavior of Xt , as t goes to infinite , where  Xt is the solution of the sde $$dX(t) = e^{-t}X(t)dB(t)$$ ?

Comment: You should try. Where is your try.

Comment: Please add your solution

Comment: Well i have tried thats why i'm asking.I have solved the sde and the solution is $$X_t= X_0 \exp\left( \frac14\ ( {{e}^{-2t}-1} ) +\int_{0}^{t}e^{-s}dB_s\right)\quad $$ but i dont know what arguments to use for the limiting behavior of the integral term.